# How to check if an FTP file exists

Tags: r, curl, sftp

I am trying to check if a file exists on my ftp server.

I've tried using the packages `httr` and `httr2` but haven't gotten it to work. Below are my attempts:

```
my_file_url <- "sftp://my_server/my_file.txt"
```

##### With `httr`

```
httr::HEAD(my_file_url, httr::authenticate(my_username, my_password))
```

Fails with the below message

```
Error in x$headers$`content-type` : 
  $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

##### With `httr2`

```
request(my_file_url) %>% 
  req_method("HEAD") %>% 
  req_auth_basic( my_username, my_password) %>% 
  req_perform()
```

Fails with the following message (I checked my credentials):

```
Error:
! Authentication failure
```

- What am I doing wrong in these two attempts?
- How do I do it directly through the `curl` package?

P.S. I tried the following, but this downloads the file:

```
curl::curl_fetch_memory(my_file_url, handle = my_curl_handle)
```

Comment: FTP is not SFTP (and vice versa).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you can pass HTTP methods (`HEAD`) or authenticate headers to (s)ftp service, but if your permissions allow you to get a directory listing, this might work:

```r
library(curl)
#> Using libcurl 8.3.0 with Schannel
# https://test.rebex.net/ demo server
SFTP_DEMO <- "sftp://demo:password@test.rebex.net:22/"

file_list <- 
  curl(url = SFTP_DEMO, handle = new_handle(dirlistonly = TRUE)) |> 
  readLines()

file_list
#> [1] "."          ".."         "pub"        "readme.txt"

"readme.txt" %in% file_list
#> [1] TRUE

"im-not-here" %in% file_list
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, you can pass authentication to `curl` like this `curl::handle_setopt(handle, userpwd = "username:password")`.

I will keep your solution for now, it suits me fine, and I will search a bit more, since this assumes that the folder exists, so I need to check if the folder exists as well . It is doable, but I was hoping for a curl result like Status:200 or STATUS: 401 or similar so I can extract a simple answer if the file exists or not